# Batch Processing on Multiple Servers

Tags: c#, batch-processing

There is a multi threaded batch processing program, that creates multiple worker threads to process each batch process.

Now to scale the application to handle 100 million records, we need to use a server farm to do the processing of each batch process. Is there native support on C# for handling requests running on a server farm? Any thoughts on how to setup the C# executable to work with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a manager that distributes the work like fejesjoco said or you can make your apps smart enough to only grab a certain number of units of work to process on.  When they have completed processing of those units, have them contact the db server to get the next batch.  Rinse and repeat until done.

As a side note most distributed worker systems run by:

1. Work is queued in server by batches
2. Worker Processes check in with server to get a batch to operate on, the available batch is marked as being processed by that worker.
3. (optional) Worker Processes check back in with server with status report (ie: 10% done, 20% done, etc)
4. Worker process completes work and submits results.
5. Go to step 2.

Another option is to have 3 workers process the exact same data set.  This would allow you to compare results.  If 2 or more have identical results then you accept those results.  If all 3 have different results then you know there is a problem and you need to inspect the data/code.  Usually this only happens when the workers are outside of your control (like SETI) or you are running massive calculations and want to correct for potential hardware issues.

Sometimes there is a management app which displays current number of workers and progress with entire set.  If you know roughly how long an individual batch takes then you can detect when a worker died and can let a new process get the same batch.

This allows you to add or remove as many individual workers as you want without having to recode anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's builtin support for clustering. In the most simple case, you might try creating a simple manager application which divides the input among the servers, and your processes will not need to know about each other, so no need to rewrite anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not deploy the app using a distributed framework?  I'd recommend [CloudIQ Platform](http://www.appistry.com)  You can use the platform to distribute your code to any number of servers.  It also handles the load balancing, so you would only need to submit your jobs to the framework, and it will handle job distribution to the individual machines.  It also monitors application execution, so if one of the machines suffers a failure, the jobs running there will be restarted on another machine in the group.

Check out the [Community](http://www.appistry.com/community) link for downloads, forums, etc.